# Solve cubic root equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, cubics

$ \sqrt[3]{x+5} - \sqrt[3]{x-5} = 1 $

How many values of x satisfy the equation?

Comment: Looks like $x=2\sqrt{13}$ is the only real root. Are you allowing complex numbers as solutions?

Comment: @AdrianKeister There is just one solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We know that $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc).$$
Also, $$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc=\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2\geq0,$$ where the equality occurs for $a=b=c.$

Now, let $\sqrt[3]{5+x}=a$, $\sqrt[3]{5-x}=b$ and $-1=c$.

Thus, since $a+b+c=0$ and $a=b=c$ is impossible, we obtain that our equation is equivalent to
$$5+x+5-x-1+3\sqrt[3]{(5-x)(5+x)}=0$$ or
$$(5-x)(5+x)=-27,$$ which gives the set of roots:
$$\{-2\sqrt{13},2\sqrt{13}\}.$$
Id est, we have two values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just one and the answer is given by Mathematica!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $$a=\sqrt[3]{x+5}$$ and $$b=\sqrt[3]{x-5}$$ so we get
$$a-b=1$$ and $$a^3-b^3=10$$ and this is easy to solve.

Comment: how do you get a^3 - b^3 = 10?

Comment: $$a^3=x+5,b^3=x-5$$ so $$a^3-5=x$$ and $$b^3=a^3-10$$